# Straight line programs with $\sqrt{~}$

Tags: arithmetic-circuits

A straight line program with division is very powerful https://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2012/10/16/one-mans-floor-is-another-mans-ceiling/.

Is it possible to reduce a straight line program with $\sqrt{~}$ allowed to one in which $\sqrt{~}$ not allowed without increasing the program size too much?